Security when instantiate Smart Contract
i am new to smart contract development and i decide to use Ink as a way to learn more about blockchain and Dapps. I was curious about what if an unauthorized actor could instantiate a new instance of my contract. Would this person cause chaos to  my system. I know this seem like a bit of noob question but i just need to hear it from someone experienced.

No. If you upload a new smart contract, others can use it in the way the smart contract allows them to. If anybody deploys the same smart contract (does not matter how they get the code), this contract is a separate program that does not have anything to do with yours, since they do not share any state.
